# Busy Indicator not working - openui5

Tags: sapui5

Below is the code in view.js:

```
chart1 = new sap.ui.core.HTML({
            content:  "<div id=\"sdtochart1\" style=\"width: 100%; \"></div>",
            layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "XL12 L12 M12 S12"}),
                                        })
```

The below code is placed in onAfterRendering in controller.js

```
var bBusy = !chart1.isBusy();
        chart1.setBusy(bBusy);
```

The intention above is to show busy indicator till the content of the html is loaded completely. But I dont see any busy indicator.

Comment: Is the `<div>` height big enough for the busy indicator to show?

Comment: Ya I got it now. But it once starts and then refuses to stop

Comment: Can you share your code where you set the busy indicator off again?

Comment: I am just doing  chart1.setBusy(false); at the end of the onAfterRendering().

Comment: ? And it still shows the busy indicator? That is odd... there are no errors in the console?

Comment: my bad I did not clear the browser cache before loading. Now as per the code the busy indicator do not even show up . While the page load takes 2-3 secs but there is no busy indicator. Code format :  `onAfterRendering: function() { chart1.setBusy(true); //some code and ajax calls  chart1.setBusy(false); }`

Answer (score 1):

The id of your outermost html element has to be the same as the id of your HTML control. Otherwise the `setBusy()` function will not find the element to add the busy overlay div to.

```js
chart1 = new sap.ui.core.HTML({
        id: "sdtochart1",
        content:  "<div id=\"sdtochart1\" style=\"width: 100%; \"></div>",
        layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "XL12 L12 M12 S12"}),
                                    })
```

Comment: while the chart1 do takes 2-3 secs to load but chart1.isBusy() always returns false not sure why.

Comment: Do you call `setBusy(true)` and `setBusy(false)` synchronously both from the `Controller.onAfterRendering()`? If so you won't see the busyindicator because it created asynchronously after the `busyIndicatorDelay`. As javascript is only singlethreaded, the `onAfterRendering` function will first run through completely. You could try to set the `busyIndicatorDelay` to `0` on your HTML control to make setBusy synchronously. Or you could instantiate the HTML control in onInit with busy = true.

Comment: Well tried all above but still the problem persists. else is there any way to check the whether the whole view is completely rendered and till then show busy indicator.

Comment: Not as far as i know. **But** you should try to separate the rendering and the data loading. Do all the data loading asynchronously. If your charting library only supports synchronous requests use f.e. [jQuery.sap.delayedCall](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.delayedCall) started from `onInit()` or even `onAfterRendering()` to encapsule the dataloading. You should then be able to set busy in onInit and reset it after the asyncronous request has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you first tried to set the HTML control as Busy ? Also the method to get the busy status is getBusy()

From the documentation:

```
getBusy(): boolean
Gets current value of property busy.
Whether the control is currently in busy state.

Default value is false.

Returns:
{boolean}   Value of property busy
```

Comment: `chart1= new sap.ui.core.HTML({
           id: "sdtochart1",
           busy: true,
              content:  "<div id=\"sdtochart1\" style=\"width: 100%; \"></div>",
              layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "XL12 L12 M12 S12"}),
          })` 
and then chart1.setBusy(false); in onAfterRendering but still dont work.